# add a new dimension and repeat values for a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a very basic question. I think this can be done elegantly in a single line with numpy, but I don't know how. Let's say I have a 2D numpy array with shape `(Nx,Ny)`, and I want to add a third dimension with shape `Nz`. For every fixed `index_x,index_y` I want to repeat the value of the array for all indices across the new z axis.

I can easily do this with basic instructions like

```
# array_1 has shape (Nx,Ny)
array_2 = np.zeros((Nx,Ny,Nz))

for idx_x in range(Nx):
    for idx_y in range(Ny):
        array_2[idx_x,idx_y,:] = array_1[idx_x,idx_y]
```

but I was wondering what is the exact numpy function to do this in a single line

Comment: `reshape`, `expend_dims` or the `[:,:,None]` idiom can be used to add a dimension.  `np.repeat` (or `np.tile`) can repeat the values.

Comment: Try `np.repeat(array_1[:, :, None], Nz, axis=2)`.

Answer (score 0):

the logic depend, every plane is the same or is linear?

Must be a cube or something else?

comes from a rectangular shape or squared?

Anyway, use [Array.reshape](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_reshape.asp)

This is a little example

```
Array2 = Array1.reshape(len(Array1), len(Array1[0]), <someValue>)
```

[Another source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: This isn't syntactically correct - mismatch in number of ( and ).

Comment: hey thank you this was a little misslook

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

As mentioned in the comments, you can add another dimension to the array and repeat along that:

```py
np.repeat(array_1[:, :, None], Nz, axis=2)
```

A better option is to use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html). You don't need to manually add a dimension and it can easily be extended to other cases when you want to repeat along one of the existing dimensions:

```py
np.tile(array_1, (1, 1, Nz))
```

Basically, you specify how many times you want to repeat the array along each axis.